# Convert older MySQL script to Postgres 9.5

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have example data (results table) that repeats like:

```
year,teacher, score, class, state
2016, Jones, 80, math 102, NC
2016, Smith, 66, history, KY
2016, Jones, 40, math 101, SC
2014, Jones, 60, science, AK
```

I want to create a new summary table (teachers) which includes teacher,score averages, year, and class ordered by teacher:

```
teacher, average, class, state
Jones, 60, 2016, math, NC SC
```

My original (older) mysql script looked similar to:

```
SELECT
  teacher, class,
  AVG(case when class rlike 'match' THEN score END) tlevel_avg,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(state) order by state SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM results
group by teacher
order by tlevel_avg desc
where year like '2012'
```

it exported to file.

I have made an attempt to get the same result with postgres but I get unique teachers with same data for each (presumabley because I created a select for avg without where for teacher value)

I am not sure how to organize this query so that avg related to specific teacher.

```
SELECT distinct teacher,
(select AVG( CASE when results.class SIMILAR TO '%math%' THEN results.score END) as training_level_avg from results)
(select AVG( CASE when results.class SIMILAR TO '%science%' THEN results.score END) as training_level_avg from results)
FROM RESULTS  
WHERE teacher NOT LIKE '%temporary%'  
AND results.year = '2011'
GROUP by results.teacher
```

Mainly I am trying to get the data returned with correctly calculated averages for all occurance for class grouped by teacher given a year, but I will also need to write this result to another 'teachers' table (bonus question).

Any help getting my over the hump is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you replace `group_concat()` with `string_agg()` and use `group by teacher, class` that should give you want you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would like like this:

```
SELECT teacher, class,
       AVG(case when class = 'match' THEN score END) as tlevel_avg,
       STRING_AGG(DISTINCT state ORDER BY state, ' ') as states
FROM results
where year = '2012' 
GROUP BY judge
ORDER BY tlevel_avg DESC;
```

`string_agg()` is the equivalent of `group_concat()`, although the syntax is slightly different.

I don't remember if there is a difference in how upper/lower case are handled.  You can replace the `= 'match'` with ilike 'match'` if case could be an issue.

Comment: I get this error when running: `ERROR:  function string_agg(character varying) does not exist
LINE 3:        STRING_AGG(DISTINCT state ORDER BY state, ' ') as sta...
               ^
HINT:  No aggregate function matches the given name and argument types. Perhaps you misplaced ORDER BY; ORDER BY must appear after all regular arguments of the aggregate. `

Comment: thanks gordon- this change seems to work: `AVG(case when class ilike '%training%' THEN score END) as tlevel_avg,
       STRING_AGG(DISTINCT state, ' ' ORDER BY state) as states`